# extra space added when going into insert mode in an abbreviation

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create an abbreviation which replace typed text by what I want but also move the cursor and enters insert mode.

the ab is as following:
`` :abbreviate MSG `MSG(("")); <Esc>F"i ``

everything works fine except when entering insert mode, I have to extra spaces before the cursor.
I've tried then to add `<BS><BS>` but it's leading to delete the first quote. Same thing if I'm putting only one `<BS>` (which is really strange, it seems the second `<BS>` has no effect at all...)

I guess I'm missing something but I can't figure out what...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

A citation from Vim help system (`:help abbreviations`):

> An abbreviation is only recognized when you type a non-keyword
>   character. This can also be the `<Esc>` that ends insert mode or the
>   `<CR>` that ends a command.  The non-keyword character which ends the
>   abbreviation is inserted after the expanded abbreviation.  An
>   exception to this is the character `<C-]>`, which is used to expand an
>   abbreviation without inserting any extra characters.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> :ab hh       hello
>        "hh<Space>" is expanded to "hello<Space>"
>        "hh<C-]>" is expanded to "hello"
> ```

So if you press `<Space>` after entering `MSG` a space is inserted *after* expanding your abbreviation.

To avoid adding a needless space you can invoke the abbreviation with pressing `<C-]>` after entering `MSG` or you can try elaborate a mapping like this:

```
:inoremap MSG `MSG(("")); <C-O>F"
```

But IMHO such a mapping is very inconvenient.

Another option may be to use use one of the many abbreviation plugins like [this](https://github.com/jiangmiao/advancer-abbreviation) (first shown by Google).

Comment: thanks for this plugin, I will take a look at it.

ok for the extra space added because I press it at the end of abbreviation but in my case, it is not 1 but 2 spaces added

Comment: @Bladehoarse: "not 1 but 2 spaces added" -- cannot reproduce. I've copied an abbreviation command from your question and pasted it into the Vim command line. And I've got one space added, not two. I've got the same behavior after starting "clear" Vim instance without any plugins and scripts  (start Vim as `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`). Can you try this abbreviation with a clear Vim?

Comment: indeed, I also have only 1 space added when starting a clear vim instance. I will take a look a my plugins and scripts and find the faulty one